# Reposition elements after removing the line

Tags: jasper-reports

I have some accounting report's summary with such rows: vat, net, total. How can I reposition some row after another was removed because it was empty?

For example, if vat is empty, I set 'Remove line when blank' and 'Blank when null' - this will remove the line from the template. But I need to reposition the net and total rows.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make "Remove line when blank" work (with automatic reposition of all elements) you should check that:

1. Textfield's value is empty
2. Textfield's "Remove line when blank" is checked
3. Textfield's Position type is setted to "Float"
4. Textfields are not touching each other